# Exim4 sends strange emails on root

Tags: debian, email, exim

Not so long ago I have found that exim is sending mail4root emails and logs them into `/var/mail/mail`. Example from exim log:

`2016-07-19 09:39:02 1bPOgI-000370-1Q <= root@example.net U=root P=local S=78459
2016-07-19 09:39:02 1bPOgI-000370-1Q => /var/mail/mail <root@example.net> R=mail4root T=address_file
2016-07-19 09:39:02 1bPOgI-000370-1Q Completed
2016-07-19 09:40:18 Start queue run: pid=12117
2016-07-19 09:40:18 End queue run: pid=12117
2016-07-19 10:09:02 1bPP9K-00042T-LK <= root@example.net U=root P=local S=78459
2016-07-19 10:09:02 1bPP9K-00042T-LK => /var/mail/mail <root@example.net> R=mail4root T=address_file
2016-07-19 10:09:02 1bPP9K-00042T-LK Completed
2016-07-19 10:10:18 Start queue run: pid=15678
2016-07-19 10:10:18 End queue run: pid=15678`

Can someone explain what causes it?

Comment: `R=mail4root` indicates that you have a router of that name in your config. Presumably, its purpose is to pass messages addressed to root to the `address_file` transport, which in turn delivers them to `/var/mail/mail`. Are you using the default exim config for your OS?

Comment: @D_Bye Yes, default installations. I found out what was the problem, `php-snmp` was not configured. I just did `apt-get install snmp`. Turned out these emails was not the cause, but the symptom. Looks like somewhere in the system there is a problem with dependencies and some task calls php-snmp periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security measure Exim will not deliver email to `root`.   The `mail4root` router is a last ditch handler to deliver mail for `root` to the mailbox for `mail`.

Normally, an alias for root would be configured in `/etc/aliases` to deliver to the system administrator's personal mailbox.  There are a number of aliases that redirect to `root` as they should be handled by the system administrator (root).  They also get redirected if the alias exists.